# Is there a xbuild build task for mdtool?

Tags: svn, xbuild, mdtool

I'm trying to automate my build process for MonoTouch and Mono for Android and having issues with the MSBuild task.  Unfortunately the MSBuild task fails, but mdtool works fine, so I'm guessing MSBuild doesn't use mdtool.

Is there an MDTOOL build task or do I have to wing it?

Is there an SVN build task for xbuild?

Thanks,
Kenny.

Comment: I've had the same problem calling `mdtool` from MSBuild.  It seems to have something to do with I/O redirection.